# Post method of HTTPUrlConnection leads to SocketTimeoutException, CLOSE_WAIT state for TCP connection

Tags: java, post, tcp, tomcat7, httpurlconnection

I am using Tomcat 7.0.59, on opening a connection with `GET` method i am able to get the response from the server. However, the `POST` request is hung till the timeout occurs. On running `netstat -nat | grep CLOSE_WAIT`, i get tcp connection in this state.

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:687)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1323)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
```

Comment: So you aren't closing the input stream when you catch `SocketTimeoutException.`

Comment: I am closing the input/output streams used in finally block